# Wicd+wpa_supplicant how to: NOT use certificates (PEAP+MSCHAP)? Enable logging?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-jessie, wpa-supplicant, wicd

I'm using Debian 8 (Jessie) with LDXE, Wicd, and wpa_supplicant, to try to connect to my work's WiFi network.  The network uses PEAP and MSCHAP, but it does not use certificates.

When I leave the certificate path blank in the Wicd network Properties dialog, I get the following messages in /var/log/wicd/wicd.log:

```
2016/01/29 07:10:16 :: Attempting to authenticate...
2016/01/29 07:10:17 :: Ignoring template line: '            ca_cert="$_CA_CERT"
2016/01/29 07:10:17 :: '
2016/01/29 07:10:52 :: wpa_supplicant authentication may have failed.
```

I have found solutions on the Web for NetworkManager-based setups that suggest setting system-ca-certs to false, but I'm not using NetworkManager.  If I understand correctly, system-ca-certs is just telling NetworkManager how to configure or pass arguments to wpa_supplicant.

How do I configure Wicd and/or wpa_supplicant to know that I don't need a certificate for this network?

(Incidentally, if someone can suggest how to find/enable wpa_supplicant logging, perhaps that would provide more insight into the problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

For my specific network, the solution was to select "PEAP with GTC" instead of the other PEAP option.

Getting wpa_supplicant logging turned out to be dead simple: there's a check box in the Wicd preferences dialog to enable debug logging, and that added wpa_supplicant log messages into the wicd log.  Specifically, it reveals the wpa_supplicant command line being used, which I was able to execute myself at a shell in order to get even more hints.